# @Binding var versus let Binding

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, binding

I was reading an article which had the following quote: "...You are using a let of type Binding instead of an @Binding property because you don’t need this view to be recomputed when the value changes. You’re only interested in sending the results of a tap up to the parent view."

I've been experimenting to try and understand the difference between using `@Binding var` and `let someConstant: Binding<someType>` and they seem to have exactly the same effect.

For example:

```
struct PlayButton: View {
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool // does the same thing as let isPlaying: Binding<Bool> and then use wrappedValue at call sites

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isPlaying.toggle()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: isPlaying ? "pause.circle" : "play.circle")
        }
    }
}

struct PlayerView: View {
    var episode = Episode()
    @State private var isPlaying: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(episode.title)
            Text(episode.showTitle)
            PlayButton(isPlaying: $isPlaying)
        }
    }
}
```

when would I want to use one over the other, and what is the benefit of using `let Binding` over `@Binding`? Hoping someone can elaborate. Cheers.

Comment: For the way that you are using it, it is functionally equivalent. And as a result, you would simply use the property wrapper. However, you can't set property observers on a wrapped property, but you can put a getter and setter on the custom binding so that you can do work when the variable changes. Now, with `.onChanged` that isn't even necessary. At this point, I don't know of any benefit. What article were you reading? The author may have had something in there that gives some use. Also, it may be an older article.

Comment: @Yrb thanks a lot for the answer. The article is here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/26733845-swiftui-view-preferences-tutorial-for-ios

Comment: It looks like just what they said. `@Binding` will cause a redraw, but `let onTap: Binding<Int>` won't cause a redraw. I suspect you wouldn't notice the difference in looking at it, as SwiftUI is pretty smart about what to redraw and what not to...